# Height-Mapped Font

Tags: fonts, 3d

Is there a place, or at least a single font out there that is bump-map friendly? By that, I mean a font that can be like [Milano LET](http://www.fontsplace.com/milano-let-free-font-download.html), but instead of using color for reflection effects, it's used for defining how elevated it would be if it were carved into a stone or imprinted into metal like this:

[image]

The letters on the cap appear to be 3D (which is actually my intended use)

Comment: a quick google search for "engraved font" will bring you many results with such fonts.

Comment: @Luciano That's exactly the type of thing I was looking for! thanks! Could you put that as an answer so that I can set this question to "Answered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is **Engraved**. A quick google search returns many results, similar to the example:

[image]

You might also be able to obtain the same result by applying a Bevel effect to the font (the specifics will depend on what 3D package you're using).